# setting environment variable in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to create a virtualenv(stage) in Jenkins and setting the needed environment variables before the virtualenv can be created.

```
        stage('create virtualenvironment') {
            sh 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv:$PATH'
            sh 'export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python'
            sh 'export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv'
            sh 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
            echo 'createvirtualenvwrapper'
            sh 'mkvirtualenv testproject'
        }
```

When I execute this script - I get this message -

```
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

When I print all the above env variables nothing is set? Not sure if the sh command is working as expected in scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but my guess is that, when you do a `sh 'Some command'` it executes a shell script and it is done.

So what is happening is that, each of your sh commands is being treated as a separate shell script which is executing the commands  and is alive only for that session and closes once the script is done.

So try to combine all of the above commands to a single sh command along with the `mkvirtualenv testproject` and it should work.

For readability create a new Shell script like  `runProject.sh` and the above commands in this shell script and then you can just call

```
sh runProject.sh
```

Hope it helps :)